# Rotas personalizadas no Laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel-5

Aos que trabalham com `Laravel`, saberiam me informar fontes para que eu possa pesquisar sobre como criar `URL's` limpas e amigáveis de forma que, eu possa passar uma parâmetro, por exemplo, `category_name`, ou `product_name`, e o sistema de `routes` reconheça e faça a chamada da `view` correspondente?

***Detalhe:*** não quero ter que passar um prefixo do tipo `categoria/category_name`, `produto/product_name`, porque assim eu fiz o teste e funciona certinho.

A ideia é, pegar o valor da url, chegar no banco de dados nas tabelas relacionadas e ver qual dá match pra ai decidir se é um categoria, uma subcategoria, uma loja, um produto, acredito que o caminho não seja esse, mesmo porque o `Laravel` tende a tornar tudo simples, e dessa forma está complexo.

*Agradeço a quem puder me dar uma orientação por onde seguir, um artigo falando sobre isso já seria de grande ajuda e um bom começo para mim.*

Comment: **Pergunto:** você quer passar por exemplo:  `rota/{variavel}` conforme a variável, tenha um decisão é um método do controle que faça a chamada de um determinado `model` e sua `view` correspondente???

Answer (score -1):

Para recuperar algum dado da URL, você pode usar um parâmetro direto na rota utilizando um nome de variável entre chaves, desta forma:

```
Route::get('categoria/{categoria}', function($categoria) { return response($categoria); })
```

O resultado disso pode ser testado da seguinte forma, ao entrar em: `localhost:8000/categoria/carros`, o valor "carros" será colocado na variável `$categoria`, que pode ser usado em qualquer lugar.
(Nesse caso de exemplo, um *response* `carros` será *printado* na tela)

Mais detalhes podem ser encontrados na documentação em [Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-parameters).

Comment: "Detalhe: não quero ter que passar um pré-fixo do tipo categoria/category_name, produto/product_name". Valeu pela resposta amigo, mas dessa forma eu já fiz. Quero fazer sem o prefixo

Comment: @SamuelDosSantos `Route::get('categoria/{categoria}', function($categoria) { return view('category_' . $categoria); })` se navegar `/categoria/xyz` vai carregar o view `category_xyz` e `Route::get('produto/{produto}', function($produto) { return view('product_' . $produto); })` se navegar `/produto/xyz` vai carregar o view `product_xyz`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento já é uma outra ideia, mas a url não está 'limpa'. Exemplo do Zoom https://www.zoom.com.br/notebook

Comment: Pensei em por exemplo: passar a url com prefixo categoria/category_name e então armazenar na sessão. Uma vez armazenado, eu redireciono para category_name e passo a trabalhar com a sessão nas rotas. É um método recomendado ou seria uma gambiarra esse tipo de procedimento?

Comment: @SamuelDosSantos Usar sessão só pra limpar a URL é uma péssima ideia, primeira que isto vai quebrar teu SEO, segundo que é o uso por um capricho denecessário, terceiro a URL tem que ser intuitiva ao usuário, se tiver o /categoria/ e o /produto/ você pode até limpar mas vai deixar bem mais confuso. Fora que seria muito trabalho pra praticamente retorno nenhum.

Comment: @SamuelDosSantos Ah, não tinha entendido direito, então, isso que você quer até é possível, mas ficaria estranho caso você tenha mais do que apenas categorias (se perceber o exemplo do Zoom é só categorias), você pode simular algo usando JS, estilo SPA, as rotas são dadas tanto no laravel quanto num Angular da vida, no JS tu usa uma rota mais "limpa" mas puxa os dados da rota mais "complexa" do laravel, mas cara se é só pra ficar mais limpo, tu vai estar criando muita dificuldade por perfumaria.

Comment: Realmente, depois da conversa aqui com você e com alguns amigos programadores, vi que não vale a pena investir nesse tipo de solução por agora. Obrigado a todos pelas respostas e pelo tempo dedicado.